# Understanding JOIN Syntax

Tags: postgresql, join

Given:

```
postgres=# \d foo
                Table "public.foo"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 a      | integer |           | not null | 
 b      | text    |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "foo_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (a)

postgres=# \d bar
                Table "public.bar"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 a      | integer |           | not null | 
 b      | text    |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "bar_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (a)

postgres=# select * from foo;
 a |  b  
---+-----
 1 | one
(1 row)

postgres=# select * from bar;
 a |  b  
---+-----
 2 | two
(1 row)
```

I then `join`'d using the following JOIN syntax:

```
postgres=# select * from foo, bar;
 a |  b  | a |  b  
---+-----+---+-----
 1 | one | 2 | two
(1 row)
```

Then, I compared it to `full outer join`:

```
postgres=# select * from foo full outer join bar using (a);
 a |  b  |  b  
---+-----+-----
 1 | one | 
 2 |     | two
(2 rows)
```

and `cross join`:

```
postgres=# select * from foo cross join bar;
 a |  b  | a |  b  
---+-----+---+-----
 1 | one | 2 | two
(1 row)
```

Is it always true that the `from a, b, c` will produce a `cross join`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Akina says in his comment, "," and CROSS JOIN is equivalent:

```
A, B   <=>    A CROSS JOIN B
```

This is also known as CARTESIAN PRODUCT. The result will have a cardinality (size) of:

| A, B | = | A | * | B |

We can restrict the result so that it becomes a subset of the CROSS JOIN like:

```
A, B WHERE <some condition>
```

The corresponding operation becomes

```
A INNER JOIN B ON <some condition>
```

INNER can be left out:

```
A JOIN B ON <some condition>
```

OUTER JOIN is a bit more complicated to explain in terms of sets, but let's start with a LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON <some condition>
```

This means:

```
A JOIN B ON <some condition>
UNION
A WHERE it does NOT EXISTS a corresponding B
```

I deliberately left out any information regarding columns in the resultset.

```
A RIGHT OUTER JOIN B ON <some condition>
```

is equal to

```
A JOIN B ON <some condition>
UNION
B WHERE it does NOT EXISTS a corresponding A
```

Finally FULL OUTER JOIN is a UNION between a LEFT and a RIGHT outer JOIN:

```
A FULL OUTER JOIN B ON <some condition>
```

is equal to:

```
A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON <some condition>
UNION
A RIGHT OUTER JOIN B ON <some condition>
```

To get it completely right we would need to extend the explanation with the columns involved.

I use to think that the "," notation was short and sweet, but after spending years and years of tuning, modifying and extending existing SQL I now prefer the ANSI JOINs over the "," ones. As shown in the comments by ypercubeᵀᴹ [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e0417f80816a0ddce16c65c1ed1028aa) strange things can happen if you have a "," join and the extend it with an ANSI join. I also find it much easier to convince myself that I have gotten the join conditions correct when they are closely located with the join, instead of the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM A
JOIN B
    ON ...
   AND ...
JOIN C
    ON ...
   AND ...
```

vs

```
SELECT ... 
FROM A, B, C
WHERE ...
  AND ...
  AND ...
  AND ...
```